# Nested Cell to string

Tags: sql, matlab

I have the following problem:

**Objective** (high-level): 
I would like to convert ESRI Shapefiles into SQL spatial data. For that purpose, I need to adapt the synthax.

**Current status / problem:**
I constructed a the following cell array:

```
'MULTIPOLYGON('    {1x2332 cell}    ','    {1x916 cell}    ','    {1x391 cell}    ','    {1x265 cell}    ')'
```

with in total 9 fields. This cell array contains the following 'nested' cell arrays: {1x2332 cell}, {1x916 cell}, {1x391 cell}, {1x265 cell}. As an example, 'nested' cell {1x2332 cell} has the following form:

```
'(('    [12.714606000000000]    [42.155628000000000]    ','    [12.702529999999999]    [42.152873999999997]    ',' ... ','    [12.714606000000000]    [42.155628000000000]    '))'
```

However, I would like to have the entire cell array (including all 'nested cells') as one string without any spaces (except the space between the numbers (coordinates)). Would you have an idea how I could get to a solution?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you mean "without any spaces"? So the desired result would be `MULTIPOLYGON(((12.71460600000000042.155628000000000,...`? You probably need at least a space between different numbers

Comment: Hi Luis, absolutely correct. I apologize - I need to have a space between the numbers (coordinates). I did correct it in the question above. .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need loops for this.

Consider a smaller example:

```matlab
innerCell1 = {'((' [12.714606000000000] [42.155628000000000] ',' [12.702529999999999] [42.152873999999997] ',' [12.714606000000000] [42.155628000000000] '))'};
outerCell = {'MULTIPOLYGON(' innerCell1 ',' innerCell1 ')'};
```

You can go along these lines:

```matlab
outer = outerCell; %// will be overwritten
ind_outer = find(cellfun(@iscell, outer)); %// positions of inner cell arrays in `outer`
for m = ind_outer
    inner = outer{m};
    ind_inner = cellfun(@isnumeric, inner); %// positions of numbers in `inner`
    ind_inner_space = find(ind_inner(1:end-1) & ind_inner(2:end)); %// need space
    ind_inner_nospace = setdiff(find(ind_inner), ind_inner_space); %// don't need
    for n = ind_inner_space
        inner{n} = [num2str(inner{n}) ' ']; %// convert to string with space
    end
    for n = ind_inner_nospace
        inner{n} = num2str(inner{n}); %// convert to string, without space
    end
    outer{m} = [inner{:}]; %// concatenate all parts of `inner`
end
str = [outer{:}]; %// concatenate all parts of `outer`
```

This results in the string

```matlab
str =
MULTIPOLYGON(((12.7146 42.1556,12.7025 42.1529,12.7146 42.1556)),((12.7146 42.1556,12.7025 42.1529,12.7146 42.1556)))
```

Comment: Thanks Luis. There is still a space between the y-coordinate and the comma: e.g.  `42.1556 ,` - how can I get rid of it?

Comment: See edit. Now a space is added only if the next element is also a number

Comment: @Turi If you don't want any spaces before or after certain characters, it may be easier to remove them than prevent them. (Check `doc strrep` for example, or `doc regexp` if it is more complicated than that)